# Calcular a media de uma matriz

Tags: python

Estava tentando calcular a media de uma matriz sem utilizar o numpy, mas n consegui chegar ao algoritimo  desejado

```
def mediah(matriz:List):
    soma = 0
    for linha in matriz:
        for aij in linha:
                soma += aij
    return soma/len(matriz)
```

Esse foi o codigo ao qual consegui chegar, mas o tipo de operação na linha 5 não é suportado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que `len(matriz)` retorna o número de linhas da matriz, não a quantidade de elementos. Já que está percorrendo a matriz, você pode somar em uma variável o tamanho de cada linha para obter a quantidade total de valores.

```
def media(matriz):
  soma = 0
  tamanho = 0

  for linha in matriz:
    soma += sum(linha)
    tamanho += len(linha)

  return soma / tamanho
```